# how can i make a web socket connection in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, websocket, connection, google-chrome-console

I'm using a website which uses Web Socket to send and get real time data. I trace it in Google Chorme and FF console and understand that after creating a web Socket use some methods in order to send and get data. Now I'm trying to imitate the procedure and manually do that! sending data which is exactly matched with the site format but I don't really know how can I make a connection and use the methods. when I traced the website I saw that some where in a code by using "this" access the connection so I couldn't find it out where the connection is created but I know all parameters of the created connection.

could anybody help me figure it out?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is not need for creating a new `WebSocket` connection, you can access the existing one by going to the devtools **Memory** tab, creating a snapshot:

[image]

Searching the snapshot for `WebSocket`:

[image]

Then saving the appropriate `WebSocket` object as a global variable (right click the object and select the **Store as global variable** option):

[image]